# Twig - assume variables as object methods

Tags: php, zend-framework, twig

This is a strange one. I'm trying to implement a 1:1 relationship between Twig and some ViewModel objects, such that Twig is aware of its context and assumes variables are methods on the object.

For example, I have a Twig template and a ViewModel_Product. I *could* do this...

```
$template->render(array('product', $product));
```

...and in the template...

```
<p>{{ product.name }}</p>
```

However, because the only thing that will ever be passed to the template is the model, it seems pointless to have users prefix each variable. Better usage would be:

```
$template->render(array('viewModel', $product));
```

...and...

```
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the product prefix? It serves as a namespace and makes your code easier to read and extend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this would be possible because twig keeps track of other global variables in each template so how would it know if the variable {{ name }} is part of your view or some other global variable? And as it was mentioned above, having the variable prefix helps to namespace your view which makes for easier reading.

Don't be a lazy coder.